# Not call twice: result of call Single.just() from ViewModel to Activity

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2

Android Studio
In build.gradle:

```
   implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
```

In my ViewModel I test this:

```
import android.app.Application
import android.view.View
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import io.reactivex.Single

    class FilmsRxJavaViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
       
        init {
            Debug.d(TAG, "init:")
            loadData()
        }
    
        fun loadData() {
            Debug.d(TAG, "loadData: first_step")
            var dispose = Single.just(true).subscribe{it -> Debug.d(TAG, "single_result = $it")}
            dispose = Single.just(false).subscribe{it -> Debug.d(TAG, "single_result = $it")}
        }
```

And here logcat:

```
FilmsRxJavaViewModel(12149): init:
FilmsRxJavaViewModel(12149): loadData: first_step
FilmsRxJavaViewModel(12149): single_result = true
FilmsRxJavaViewModel(12149): single_result = false
```

As you can see the result of `Single.just()` **single_result** print twice. Because I twice call `Single.just()`

Nice. It's correct.

Now I want to print result of `Single.just()` in my Activity:

In my Activity:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
class FilmsRxJavaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FilmsRxJavaActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {

  val viewModelProvider = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
        filmsRxJavaViewModel = viewModelProvider.get(FilmsRxJavaViewModel::class.java)
        var dispose = filmsRxJavaViewModel.isShowProgressSingle
            ?.subscribe { it ->
                Debug.d(TAG, "initLogic: isShowProgress = $it")
            }
    }
```

In my ViewModel

```
  import android.app.Application
  import android.view.View
  import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
  import io.reactivex.Single
    
   class FilmsRxJavaViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

var isShowProgressSingle: Single<Boolean>? = null
    init {
        Debug.d(TAG, "init:")
        loadData()
    }

    fun loadData() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "loadData: first_step")
        isShowProgressSingle = Single.just(true)
        Debug.d(TAG, "loadData: second_step")
        isShowProgressSingle = Single.just(false)
    }
```

And here logcat:

```
FilmsRxJavaViewModel(12311): init:
FilmsRxJavaViewModel(12311): loadData: first_step
FilmsRxJavaViewModel(12311): loadData: second_step

FilmsRxJavaActivity(12311): initLogic: isShowProgress = false
```

As you can see in my Activity the  `isShowProgress = false`.

So it's print only once. **Why not print this (twice)**:

```
FilmsRxJavaActivity(12311): initLogic: isShowProgress = true
 FilmsRxJavaActivity(12311): initLogic: isShowProgress = false
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Single.just()` operator is a static method which creates a new object of `SingleJust<T>` class which you can subscribe to it, calling it twice doesn't mean that it will emit two items, it just creates a new object and assign it to `isShowProgressSingle`.

What you looking for is `Observable` or `Flowable` of items which can emit more than one item, for example :

```
 isShowProgressObservable = Observable.fromArray(true,false)
```

And if you want to create a stream for showing your progress a simple solution is `ReplaySubject` which is a subclass of `Observable`, you can create and use it like this :

```
 val progress = ReplaySubject.create<Boolean>()
 progress.onNext(true)
 progress.onNext(false)
 progress.subscribe{
      //do your thing
 }
```